# React-Testing-Library, I have difficulty selecting the Material entry, plus the debug cuts out

Tags: javascript

TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "textbox" and name "Contraseña"

Page for TEST:

return (

```
  <AuthLayout title='Acceso'>
     <Box component='form' aria-label='formLogin' className='login-containerForm'>
        <IconLabel name='email' onChange={onInputChange} required={true} type='email' value={email} icon='Email' iconColor='white' placeholder='Correo Electronico' validation1={!!emailValid} validation2={formSubmitted} size='medium' bgColor='primaryDarknes' iconBgColor='primaryDarknes' />

        <IconLabel name='password' onChange={onInputChange} required={true} type='password' value={password} icon='Key' iconColor='white' placeholder='Contraseña' validation1={!!passwordValid} validation2={formSubmitted} size='medium' bgColor='primaryDarknes' iconBgColor='primaryDarknes' />

        <FormMessageAlert messageControler1={emailValid} messageControler2={passwordValid} messageControler5={formSubmitted} messageError1={emailValid} messageError2={passwordValid} />
        
        <Grid container className='login-containerButton'>
           <ButtonSubmitWithIcon displayIcon='disable' title='Iniciar Sessión' isSaving={isSaving} onClick={onLogin} fontWeight='bold' backgroundColor='primaryDarknes' />
        </Grid>
     </Box>
  </AuthLayout>
```

)

Component reused: For Input

```
return (
        <Grid container aria-label='IconLabel' className='iconLabel-container'>
            <Grid item aria-label='Icon' className={`iconLabel-container-icon bgColor-${ bgColor }`}>
                <IconList icon={icon} backgroundColor={iconBgColor} color={iconColor} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item aria-label='Input' className='iconLabel-container-input'>
                <TextField
                    aria-label='TextField'
                    autoComplete={autoComplete}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    error={validation1 && validation2}
                    fullWidth
                    label={placeholder}
                    name={name}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    required={required}
                    size={size}
                    type={type}
                    value={value}
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
```

test('2.- Invalid email notification should be reflected when entering incorrect email', () => {
const email = 'correo.com'
const password = '123456'

```
    render( 
        <Provider store={ store } >
            <Login /> 
        </Provider>
    )
    const input = screen.getByRole('textbox', {name: 'Contraseña'});
    fireEvent.change( input, {target: {name: 'Correo Electronico', value: email }})
    fireEvent.change( input, {target: {name: 'Contraseña' ,value: password }})

    const loginForm = screen.getByLabelText('formLogin');
    fireEvent.submit( loginForm )

    screen.debug( input )
});
```

Comment: Please keep the question in english on this site.